# PHP: time difference as time in three time zones

Tags: php, time

I have a problem which I dont know how to solve.
Here is example:

```
$time_start = "13:30";
$time_finish = "03:00";
```

The worker starts working at 13:30 and finishes next day at 3:00.
There are three zones (paid differently): 6:00-13:59,14:00-21:59,22:00-5:59

I need an output in hours which will tell me how many hours the worker was working in which zone. It will take only halfs of hours.

So in this example it would be:

> 1st zone - 0.5 , 2nd zone - 8 , 3rd zone - 5

I hope its understandable.
Thank you very much!

Comment: I would not use the term "time zone" in this context as it's a fixed term for the planet's time zones. Not sure what a better term would be though... Also, this is very broad. What exactly are you looking for, or stuck with?

Comment: Yea thats right. Well, I know how to calculate the time difference between two times, but I dont know the best way how to split this time to these three "zones". Only thing that came to my mind was to take each hour from start time until the midnight or until the finish time and than in some loop let the script decide which "zone" this hour belongs to.

Answer (score 0):

As follows you can calculate the time difference.

```
$t1=mktime(13,0,0,5,20,2012);
$t2=mktime(13,0,0,5,30,2012);

echo date("H:s:i", ($t2-$t1));
```

Take a look at http://php.net/manual/es/function.mktime.php

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but this is not what I was asking for, I know how to calculate the time difference, my problem is that I dont know how have the output for each "time zone" in hours.